# ¿Es posible cambiar el valor de un ng-model mediante un filtro?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy elaborando un `array` , pero quiero cambiar el valor mostrado en la vista según algunas evaluaciones.

estaría mostrando los valores así.

```
<div ng-repeat="valor in bonos">
 <label>{{valor.nombre |filtro: myfuncion}}</label>
</div>
```

Entonces en mi función quiero retornar un nuevo valor para `valor.nombre`

```
vm.myfunction = funcion(valorAntiguo){
  return nuevoValor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas pasar un filtro, puedes definir un método donde se evalúe y retorne un valor modificado, y llamarlo cuando se vaya a escribir el valor original.

Algo como esto (que procesa las cadenas y las convierte a mayúscula):

```js
var app = angular.module("miApp", []);
app.controller("miCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.array = ["álvaro", "lucas", "sofía"];
  $scope.miFormato = function(valor) {
    return valor.toUpperCase();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="miApp" ng-controller="miCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="val in array">
    {{ miFormato(val) }}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: esto funciona muy bien , y para este caso no era necesario un filtro ya que lo ocupaba solo en este controlador , si necesitara expandirlo ahí necesitaria el filtro

Answer (score 1):

Si pasas como parametro una función al filtro entones debes retornar la llamada a dicha función desde el filtro.

```
app.filter('filtro', function() {
    return function(input, myfuncion) {
        return myfuncion();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola si así como tu lo escribes lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma,

```
<div ng-repeat="valor in bonos">
 <label>{{valor.nombre |filtro: myfuncion(valor)}}</label>
</div>


vm.myfunction = funcion(valor){
  valor.nombre = 'nuevoValor';
}
```

Con eso la referencia queda indicada y puedes cambiar el valor desde la funcion.

Comment: esto funciona bien , pero me genera una duda y un problema de rendimiento, una vez que termina el ng-repeat, si voy al código y agrego un breakpoint me doy cuenta que aun sigue ejecutando la función aunque ya aya terminado el ng-repeat